# Where to use Lambda Expression

Tags: lambda

What are the different scenario in which we can use Lambda Expression. One of the scenarios is with LINQ Queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anywhere you want to create a delegate or an expression tree, basically. Some examples outside LINQ:

- The old-style `List<T>.ConvertAll`/`FindAll` etc methods
- Starting new threads / tasks
- Attaching event handlers
- Providing an action in unit tests (e.g. "this action should throw an exception")
- Providing a value on request for `Lazy<T>`